# Android ArCore Sceneform API. How to change textures in runtime?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

The server has more than 3000 models and each of them has several colors of material. I need to load separately models and textures and set textures depending on the user's choice. How to change baseColorMap, normalMap, metallicMap, roughnessMap in runtime?

after
modelRenderable.getMaterial().setTexture("normalMap", normalMap.get());
nothing happens
I'm doing something wrong. There is no information in documentation for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for posting this question.

- **`setTexture()` appears to not work**: Unfortunately this part of our API is still a little rough; it works but is very easy to get wrong. We're working on a sample to illustrate how to modify material parameters (including textures) at runtime and will improve our error reporting in the next release.
- **Thousands of models w/ multiple permutations how?**: The plan here has two parts:

  - The binaries used by the Android Studio plugin will be made available for use in build scripts on server platforms.  This will allow you to do a server-side conversion of your assets to `.sfb`.  We'll be releasing a blog post soon on how to do this.
  - The `.sfa` will get the ability to contain loose textures and materials not explicitly associated with geometry, and `.sfa`'s will be able to declare data dependencies on other `.sfa`'s.  This will mean that you can author (and deliver) `.sfb`'s that contain textures/materials (but no geometry) and `.sfb`'s that contain geometry (but no textures/materials), and if they're both available at instantiation time it will just work.

Answer (score 1):

use this code`

```
CompletableFuture<Texture> futureTexture = Texture.builder()
          .setSource(this, R.drawable.shoes)
          .build();
```

and replace with

```
/*.thenAccept(renderable -> andyRenderable = renderable)*/
        .thenAcceptBoth(futureTexture, (renderable, texture) -> {
            andyRenderable = renderable;
            andyRenderable.getMaterial().setTexture("baseColor", texture);
        })
```

would work.

Comment: Its wotks only for baseColor, but what about normaMap?"